# For Pokemon Go, is it possible to find out the "perfection" percentage without doing a "power up" or "evolve"?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have seen video that says we can use an IV calculator such as:

https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator

to first find out the possible perfection %, and then keep on "power up" or "evolve", and use the Refine button and you can narrow down the real number for this Pokemon.

For example, it could be 67.8%, 82.2%, 94.8% (just an example), and after some power up and/or evolve, you can narrow down it to 82.2%

But I also have seen a video that says you can go to some website and type in your gmail log in, and it will tell you the perfection % of every single Pokemon that you have.  So I presume that will mean you don't have to waste stardust and candies to do the narrow down.

Is it really possible to know the perfection % without using stardust and candies to do the narrow down?

Comment: If you actually give someone your gmail credentials, chances are good they won't be nice to it.

Comment: unless if that gmail account was created just for playing Pokemon Go, then there should be less risk

Comment: Less risk, but chances of actually getting the expected data is virtually nil.

Comment: I would stay _FAR_ away from that site if I were you.

Comment: actually, I have seen one English version of the website and one Japanese version of another website, for what it looked like by long time Pokemon fans...

Comment: @太極者無極而生 you can use those sites, not sure why those guys are frekaing out. Gmail credentials are verified using an authentication key, not by giving them your user/password. These guys don't know what they're talking about. the only risk here is getting banned by Niantic, but I wouldn't worry too much about getting banned, since these sites don't actually alter data, they just intercept it to see the strength of your pokemon. BUT don't use the tools/sites that evolve pokemon for you. Then you will get banned. Just use the ones that *only* read data.

Answer (score 2):

Logging into a service that calculates your CPs is against the T&Cs of the game, and will probably get your account banned.

Since they released the in-game appraisal system, some calculators are giving pretty accurate results (e.g.  https://pokemon.gameinfo.io/en/tools/iv-calculator) when you enter the appraisal stats too.

Unfortunately you can't always guarantee that you'll be able to calculate the exact CPs (it's usually at most a range of a few percent though).

Answer (score -2):

Until recently I was using PokeAdvisor website which gave you the exact IV% of your Pokemon but also tracked some other cool stats such as balls thrown, % of nice throws, etc. Unfortunately this was shut down by Niantic... I think they are being more busy with shutting down third party sites than actually improving their game.

Anyhow back on topic: Nowadays I have been using this website https://pogobag.me/
While it is not as perfect as PokeAdvisor was, it's still much easier to check your IV's than doing it manually :-)

Comment: so in other words, it **is** possible to find out the exact IV (the exact perfection %) without using any stardust and candies?

Comment: Yes indeed, just use the pogobag site I linked above.